# filtering redis data with jpql does not work

Tags: java, spring, jpa, redis, jpql

Is it possible to create a JPQL filter with redis?

if I try this:

```
List<ContingencyDTO> findAll();
```

works:

but if i try with jpql no.

```
@Repository
public interface ContingencyRepository extends 
CrudRepository<ContingencyDTO,Integer>, QueryByExampleExecutor<ContingencyDTO>  
{

List<ContingencyDTO> findByInitialZipCodeLessThanEqual(Long initialZipCode);

}
```

return this message error:
Erro:: handleAPIException:: Exception

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: LESS_THAN_EQUAL (1): [IsLessThanEqual, LessThanEqual] is not supported for Redis query derivation!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LESS_THAN_EQUAL (1): [IsLessThanEqual, LessThanEqual] is not supported for Redis query derivation!

---

I tryed upate in DTO the filtered values to @Indexed but dont work.

```
private @Indexed Long initialZipCode;
```

Comment: did you got an error? do you know how `findByZipcode` and `findAll` works?

Comment: Erro:: handleAPIException:: Exception

org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findByZipcode found for type ContingencyDTO!
 at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>

Answer (score 0):

Please check the attribute name in Entity `ContingencyDTO`. If the attribute name is `zipcode`, then above method should have worked. If the attribute name is `zipCode` then the method name should be `findByZipCode`.

If you want to retrieve all `ContingencyDTO` entities for a given `zipCode` then `List<ContingencyDTO> findByZipCode(String zipCode);`should work. @Query annotation isn't required in this case and in above case too, if the issue is solved as per this explanation.

Comment: My Entity is not a problem... The prob. is when I try w/ redis...